# How to query virtual column using Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

There is a Sage in Student table, I want to query the year of birth of a student using `2017-Sage`, but I don't know how to do it, I have tried to do like this:

```
db.Student.findAll({
        attributes: ['Sname','Ssex',[2017-Sequelize.col('Sage'),'Year of birth']],
        where: {
            Clno: {
                $in: ['01311','10665']
            }
        }
    })
```

but it comes the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: attr[0].indexOf is not a function
```

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check the [`Sequelize.VIRTUAL`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes) datatype.

So something like this might be needed in Student model definition:

```
Student = sequelize.define('student', {
    ...
    birthYear: {
        type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL(Sequelize.INTEGER, "(2017 - `students`.age) as birthYear")
    }
}
```

More examples are available here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7350

Comment: It seems like using ticks does no longer work. Instead, you can pass a tuple with a literal and the alias through as one of the attributes the virtual column depends on: `Sequelize.VIRTUAL(Sequelize.INTEGER, [[Sequelize.literal("2017 - students.age"), "birthYear"]])`